# Flickr photo URL replacement regular expression

Tags: regex, url, flickr

I'm trying to write a regular expression to modify URLs stored in a database (linking to photos on Flickr) so I can change the size of photos already on a site -

**E.g. Replace:** 4724575242_ca7d120609.jpg **with** 4724575242_ca7d120609_z.jpg **in a URL such as:**

http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1045/4724575242_ca7d120609.jpg

The only change is to add **_z** before the .jpg extension.

I imagined that a regular expression could be written which matches **static.flickr.com** then replace **.jpg** with **_z.jpg** but unfortunately my attempts have so far failed.

I wondered if any regex ninjas out there might be able to help me with this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated - David

Comment: what scripting language?

Comment: I'm using a search & replace plugin for wordpress to do this - http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex - it just uses a generic regular expression syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one (adapting it to your language, of course) ?

```
/static\.flickr\.com\/([a-z0-9_\/]+)\.jpg$/static.flickr.com\/$1_z.jpg/
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Using the wordpress Search Regex plugin I used the search pattern:

/static\.flickr\.com\/([a-z0-9_\/]+)\.jpg/

and replace pattern:

static.flickr.com/$1_z.jpg